# Add a new column based on change in values in other columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
DF <- data.frame(Col1=c(0,0,1),Col2=c(0,1,1),Col3=c(1,0,1))
```

|  | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

I need to add a new column "Switch" that contains the name of the variable at which the value of the row has changed for the first time, so the output looks like this:

|  | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Switch |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | Col3 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | Col2 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | NA |

Any guidance or help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may use `max.col`

```
tmp <- names(DF)[max.col(DF, 'first')]
tmp[rowSums(DF == 1) == ncol(DF)|rowSums(DF == 0) == ncol(DF)] <- NA
DF$Switch <- tmp
```

-output

```
> DF
  Col1 Col2 Col3 Switch
1    0    0    1   Col3
2    0    1    0   Col2
3    1    1    1   <NA>
```

Comment: A quick follow up question - what if I have other columns (e.g., ID) in the dataframe? How can I point to the specific range of columns I want to use for comparison? Thank you

Comment: @RNewbie Just subset the columns i.e. `names(DF)[1:3][max.col(DF[1:3], "first")]` ie.everywhere we use `DF` in the code, should be a subset with only selected columns

Comment: Hello, I have another follow up question - my data in the Switch column is "Q1", Q2",  "Q3", etc. I'm trying to separate the letter "Q" from the numeric values using: DF %>% separate(DF$tmp, c(NA, "Number"), "(?<=[A-Z])(?=[0-9])" ).   I get the following error: "Error: Must extract column with a single valid subscript.
x Subscript `var` has size 452 but must be size 1. " Any help would be appreciated!!!

Comment: @RNewbie can you post as a new question

Comment: I just did - thank you.

Comment: @RNewbie Based on the syntax, I find an error.  Can you check the syntax I shsowed in solution

Answer (score 0):

You may write a function with `diff` and apply it rowwise.

```
switch_col <- function(x) {
  cols[which(diff(x) != 0)[1] + 1]
}
cols <- names(DF)
DF$switch_col <- apply(DF, 1, switch_col)
DF

#  Col1 Col2 Col3 switch_col
#1    0    0    1       Col3
#2    0    1    0       Col2
#3    1    1    1       <NA>
```

You may also use `dplyr` -

```
library(dplyr)

DF %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(switch_col = switch_col(c_across())) %>%
  ungroup
```